# How to get a "clean" list with "lapply"?

Tags: r, lapply

I'm using "lapply" for write the output of my function in txt format. But, the txt file comes with letters and numbers dirting the output, as follows:

> "x"
>
> "1"0.602059991327962

While i need only values, as follows:

> 0.602059991327962
>
> 0.698970004336019
>
> 0.778151250383644

Follows the code that i'm using:

```
box_size<-c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,27,30,33,36,40,44,48)
ninbox2 <-c(50,40,33,28,25,22,20,18,16,14,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,6,5,5,4,4)
Log_n<-0

aux_list <- lapply(seq_along(ninbox2), function(j){

  Log_n[j] <- log10(box_size[j])
  
  
})

lapply(aux_list,function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'log.txt'  , append= T, sep='' ))
```

Comment: just inside the `write.table` include `row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE`

Comment: it works perfectly,thanks!