# Clean up list output within RStudio when using lapply() or sapply()

Tags: r, list, output, lapply, r-lavaan

I have a function that I am using with lapply().

```
lapply(x, function(x))
```

The output looks like this:

```
    [[1]]
[1] "att_admire"

[[2]]
[1] "att_hypocrisy"

[[3]]
[1] "att_annoyed"

[[4]]
[1] ""

[[5]]
[1] "att_respectvalues"
```

When I use sapply(), it looks like this:

```
         att_admire       att_hypocrisy         att_annoyed           att_judge 
       "att_admire"     "att_hypocrisy"       "att_annoyed"                  "" 
  att_respectvalues 
"att_respectvalues"
```

I would like the output to look neater, like this. Only the variable names should be included, not the "" or indices.

```
att_admire, att_hypocrisy, att_annoyed, att_respectvalues
```

What can I do to modify the code I have? I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459893/how-to-get-a-clean-list-with-lapply), but it focuses on how to get cleaner results in an output file, whereas I would prefer for the output to look cleaner in RStudio itself.

---

Below, I have included the function I am using and a sample of the data.

Libraries:

```
install.packages("lavaan")
library(lavaan)
```

Main command:

```
iv <- "consistent"
dv <- "behavior_solarize"

mediators <- c("att_admire", "att_hypocrisy", "att_annoyed", "att_judge", "att_respectvalues") 

lapply(mediators, med_overall)
```

Function (using "lavaan" package):

```
med_overall <- function(mediator) {
  mediation.model <- 
paste("
  # mediator
  ",mediator," ~ a * ",iv,"
  ",dv," ~ b * ",mediator,"
  
  # direct effect
  ",dv," ~ c * ",iv,"
  
  # indirect effect (a*b)
  ab := a*b
  
  # total effect
  total := c + (a*b)")

fit <- sem(mediation.model, data = df, meanstructure = TRUE,
           se = "boot", bootstrap = 500)

val <- parameterEstimates(fit)

ifelse(val[10,8] < 0.05, mediator, "")}
```

Sample data:

```
structure(list(behavior_solarize = c(5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 
7, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 6, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 2, 6, 2, 2, 
1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 6, 4, 2, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 
1, 4, 1, 6, 7, 6, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 4, 6, 
3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 2, 6, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
4, 3, 6, 5, 5, 5, 1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 6, 6, 2, 7, 6, 5, 2, 5, 4, 1, 
7, 2, 2, 5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 6, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 
5, 4, 6, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 2, 5, 5, 
6, 5, 2, 1, 1, 4, 7, 5, 6, 2, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 6, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 
5, 5, 2, 2, 1, 2, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 5, 2, 
1, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 1, 5, 7, 2, 7, 1, 6, 3, 7, 5, 1, 5, 6, 2, 5, 
2, 6, 7, 5, 5, 2, 7, 2, 6, 5, 6, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 2, 5, 4, 
5, 1, 1, 6, 4, 3, 3, 6, 5, 5, 3, 6, 3, 6, 4, 1, 1, 4, 7, 2, 2, 
3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 5, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7, 4, 6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 6, 1, 4, 6, 5, 
6, 2, 2, 5, 4, 6, 2, 5, 5, 1, 6, 5, 3, 5, 2, 6, 6, 2, 6, 7, 5, 
3, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 4, 2, 6, 6, 6, 1, 3, 2, 6, 3, 
3, 4, 3, 6, 6, 7, 5, 7, 6, 5, 1, 3, 6, 2, 6, 6, 2, 6, 3, 4, 6, 
7, 4, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 5, 3, 
4, 6, 5, 7, 3, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 4, 6, 3, 3, 2, 5, 6, 
5, 1, 5, 7, 6, 4, 5, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5, 1, 7, 2, 6, 4, 3, 6, 6, 
4, 4, 4, 1, 6, 3, 6, 7, 5, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 5, 2, 6, 5, 5, 
7, 5, 7, 7, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 6, 3, 5, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 
2, 3, 6, 7, 7, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 1, 6, 2, 7, 5, 6, 6, 5, 2, 5, 2, 
4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 7, 2, 5, 5, 2, 5, 2, 3, 6, 5, 5, 6, 4, 
5, 5, 3, 2, 7, 3, 5, 4, 1, 4, 3, 6, 4, 1, 6, 7, 2, 4, 2, 1, 6, 
7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 4, 6, 2, 1, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 
2, 5, 5, 5, 2, 7, 5, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 6, 2, 4, 7, 6, 2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 7, 1, 
3, 4, 7, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 5, 3, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 1, 5, 6, 
6, 5, 6, 5, 4, 1, 6, 4, 1, 6, 2, 7, 1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 1, 5, 4, 7, 
3, 2, 2, 6, 5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 6, 5, 5, 2, 5, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 5, 4, 
5, 1, 5, 6, 2, 6, 1, 1, 5, 2, 3, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 5, 7, 6, 2, 
4, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 2, 3, 6), consistent = c(1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), att_admire = c(4, 
2, 6, 5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 6, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 6, 
5, 4, 4, 4, 7, 2, 3, 4, 4, 7, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 7, 4, 3, 4, 2, 
4, 3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 4, 1, 6, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 1, 4, 5, 
4, 1, 1, 5, 7, 3, 1, 7, 5, 7, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 3, 1, 
6, 4, 3, 7, 4, 2, 1, 6, 3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 4, 1, 6, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 
6, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 7, 5, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 
6, 4, 4, 5, 1, 5, 6, 1, 7, 4, 1, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 
3, 4, 5, 4, 2, 1, 7, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 
6, 2, 5, 4, 7, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 1, 3, 1, 7, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 5, 1, 6, 4, 1, 7, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 
4, 2, 5, 4, 1, 5, 5, 4, 1, 2, 7, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7, 5, 4, 
3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 
6, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 7, 7, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 4, 1, 4, 
3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 7, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 
3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 1, 7, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 5, 
6, 5, 1, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 6, 1, 7, 5, 1, 4, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 2, 
4, 6, 6, 5, 4, 1, 5, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 6, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 7, 
4, 4, 1, 6, 5, 5, 3, 4, 7, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 
1, 5, 3, 5, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 
1, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 7, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 
4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 4, 3, 7, 3, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 
4, 6, 3, 6, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 7, 2, 7, 
2, 6, 7, 4, 2, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 6, 7, 1, 5, 6, 4, 6, 
2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 1, 4, 1, 
4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5, 7, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 7, 2, 5, 4, 5, 
3, 1, 5, 2, 5, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 7, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 5, 2, 6, 5, 1, 
5, 2, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 1, 5, 2, 4, 7, 7, 1, 2, 
7, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 
5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 7, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 1, 4, 4, 6, 3, 1, 
4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 4, 1, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 
3, 6, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 3, 1, 6, 6, 4, 
6, 1, 7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 3, 1, 6), 
    att_hypocrisy = c(4, 5, 7, 2, 5, 6, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 
    5, 6, 4, 3, 7, 6, 1, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 3, 1, 3, 
    7, 1, 7, 3, 7, 1, 7, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 7, 3, 7, 
    5, 7, 4, 1, 1, 2, 6, 6, 3, 1, 5, 1, 6, 4, 6, 2, 1, 1, 7, 
    1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 4, 1, 4, 7, 7, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 7, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 
    5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 4, 6, 1, 4, 1, 
    1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 1, 3, 5, 5, 1, 6, 1, 1, 4, 3, 5, 7, 2, 3, 
    4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 5, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, 
    7, 5, 7, 7, 6, 2, 7, 1, 4, 1, 6, 2, 3, 1, 7, 7, 6, 2, 4, 
    2, 3, 1, 6, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 3, 7, 7, 6, 5, 6, 1, 7, 
    6, 3, 1, 6, 5, 6, 1, 6, 1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 7, 2, 5, 1, 
    4, 7, 1, 7, 6, 2, 1, 4, 5, 5, 1, 7, 3, 2, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 
    4, 1, 6, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 4, 7, 4, 5, 6, 
    6, 4, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 
    1, 2, 3, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 7, 5, 6, 2, 4, 
    5, 6, 2, 7, 1, 5, 4, 4, 1, 6, 1, 4, 4, 7, 3, 5, 7, 2, 7, 
    5, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 6, 1, 5, 5, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 
    5, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 1, 2, 2, 7, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 
    6, 1, 5, 6, 5, 2, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 
    3, 3, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 4, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 6, 
    1, 7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 
    4, 5, 7, 3, 2, 7, 6, 7, 7, 1, 7, 1, 6, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 
    5, 4, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 1, 5, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 
    6, 1, 7, 5, 4, 5, 3, 6, 3, 3, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 6, 1, 1, 4, 
    1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
    7, 1, 2, 7, 1, 5, 3, 7, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 6, 3, 6, 5, 
    1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 1, 6, 2, 4, 3, 2, 5, 2, 6, 1, 
    5, 1, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 4, 6, 4, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 1, 7, 3, 
    4, 1, 5, 1, 4, 7, 1, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 7, 4, 7, 2, 1, 
    7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 7, 6, 1, 7, 4, 6, 6, 1, 2, 4, 6, 2, 
    7, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 1, 1, 5, 2, 5, 1, 1, 7, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
    5, 1, 5, 2, 7, 6, 4, 1, 4, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 2, 2, 6, 3, 
    5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 5, 5, 1, 7, 2, 5, 7, 1, 6, 
    1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 1, 4, 6, 3, 5, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 
    2, 5, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 6, 2, 5, 6, 1, 6, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 3, 
    1, 7, 2, 4, 1, 7, 2, 5, 5, 4, 6, 2, 1, 6, 2), att_annoyed = c(5, 
    5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 6, 5, 1, 
    4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 6, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 2, 
    2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 7, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 
    3, 1, 1, 5, 2, 6, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1, 7, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 7, 1, 
    5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 
    1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 
    5, 2, 3, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 
    3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 7, 7, 2, 6, 2, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 
    4, 2, 6, 2, 2, 7, 5, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, 5, 5, 7, 6, 5, 2, 4, 
    1, 7, 7, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 5, 2, 
    2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 7, 7, 6, 5, 6, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 7, 1, 
    4, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 
    5, 5, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 1, 1, 4, 1, 6, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
    1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 
    1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 7, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 7, 3, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 
    4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 2, 5, 6, 1, 6, 4, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 7, 
    1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 7, 5, 7, 
    3, 3, 2, 7, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6, 2, 7, 5, 1, 5, 1, 6, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
    7, 4, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 
    7, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 7, 2, 2, 3, 7, 3, 5, 6, 2, 
    7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 
    6, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 3, 
    5, 2, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 
    3, 1, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 1, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2, 
    7, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 
    1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 6, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 5, 4, 5, 1, 
    1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 
    1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2, 1, 7, 4, 7, 3, 1, 7, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
    7, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
    1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 6, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 6, 3, 2, 
    1, 2, 6, 6, 3, 4, 4, 6, 2, 5, 2, 1, 5, 7, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 
    3, 4, 6, 4, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 5, 
    1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 7, 1, 2, 5, 2, 6, 
    6, 2, 5, 1, 1, 5, 3, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 6, 1, 4, 1, 4, 6, 
    6, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 5, 6), att_judge = c(3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 
    5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2, 
    5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 7, 3, 7, 6, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 
    1, 1, 3, 7, 4, 2, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 
    4, 6, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 1, 3, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 5, 3, 1, 1, 
    2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 3, 5, 6, 1, 1, 1, 4, 
    2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3, 
    1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 7, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 
    2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 5, 7, 3, 2, 
    5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 
    1, 1, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 1, 
    4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 2, 1, 3, 2, 
    3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 
    3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 
    3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 4, 
    4, 4, 7, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 7, 4, 4, 1, 2, 5, 
    5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 
    3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 7, 2, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 
    2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 
    1, 1, 5, 4, 3, 5, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 
    2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 6, 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 2, 
    4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 
    5, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 1, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 
    4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 
    6, 4, 7, 1, 2, 5, 1, 6, 1, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 3, 4, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 3, 
    1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 7, 1, 4, 2, 
    3, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 1, 7, 5, 5, 4, 
    5, 5, 1, 5, 6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 1, 4, 
    4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 7, 4, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 
    1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 1, 5, 1, 6, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    4, 2, 6, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 7, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 
    1, 7, 5, 3, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 7, 4, 3, 1, 7, 
    6, 4, 5, 1, 4, 5, 7, 2, 4, 4, 5, 1, 5, 5, 7, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    1, 1, 5), att_respectvalues = c(5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 7, 
    4, 5, 7, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4, 
    3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 1, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 5, 2, 7, 5, 7, 5, 4, 
    7, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 6, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4, 7, 6, 6, 5, 3, 2, 5, 
    5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 5, 4, 7, 6, 6, 4, 4, 5, 7, 
    5, 4, 2, 4, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 
    2, 5, 7, 6, 3, 7, 6, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 7, 5, 4, 6, 4, 
    4, 6, 4, 6, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 5, 3, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 
    5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 7, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 6, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 
    5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 5, 5, 7, 3, 5, 7, 5, 4, 2, 4, 
    5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 7, 4, 6, 4, 7, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 3, 
    3, 3, 6, 7, 5, 4, 7, 2, 7, 1, 4, 3, 6, 4, 4, 7, 7, 3, 6, 
    3, 6, 4, 5, 3, 3, 7, 3, 7, 4, 6, 3, 4, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
    6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 7, 4, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 
    1, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 5, 4, 7, 5, 
    4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 4, 7, 4, 4, 7, 5, 6, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 
    4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 5, 4, 7, 5, 
    6, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 3, 5, 5, 7, 1, 6, 6, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 
    4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 7, 5, 5, 6, 1, 6, 6, 7, 4, 
    7, 3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 3, 7, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 
    7, 5, 3, 7, 4, 5, 4, 6, 7, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 3, 7, 7, 5, 
    7, 4, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 7, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 4, 
    4, 7, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 4, 4, 3, 6, 4, 6, 4, 5, 5, 4, 
    4, 6, 5, 7, 3, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 4, 4, 6, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 4, 
    5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 5, 6, 6, 7, 3, 5, 6, 
    5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 7, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 3, 7, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 
    4, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7, 7, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 
    5, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 1, 3, 4, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 7, 4, 4, 
    5, 1, 5, 7, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4, 1, 7, 4, 7, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 7, 6, 4, 4, 5, 7, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 2, 4, 
    3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 2, 5, 6, 4, 6, 2, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 1, 5, 
    4, 7, 4, 5, 4, 7, 5, 4, 6, 5, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 
    5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 7, 
    7, 7, 4, 7, 4, 4, 7, 5, 5, 6, 2, 6, 5, 4, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-693L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Your example code doesn't run. Please include whichever library supplies the `sem` and `parameterEstimates` functions and check the code in the question for typos and errors.

Comment: @neilfws Added the library. I believe the only one necessary is "lavaan".

Comment: I get: `Error in lavaan::lavaan(model = mediation.model, data = df, meanstructure = TRUE, :  lavaan ERROR: data is a function; it should be a data.frame`

Comment: @neilfws I updated the data, noticed it was missing a couple columns. Does it work now?

Comment: And the dataframe needs to be named df.

Comment: Yes, I named mine `df1` to avoid confusion with the `df` function, that caused the error.

Comment: I think the simplest solution to your question is to use `sapply` instead of `lapply`. But really, there is no need for output to look clean in RStudio: the more usual approach is to assign output to a variable and then write some code to format it as you would like.

Comment: I've added the sapply() output to my original q, but it doesn't address the problem I'm trying to solve. Why would sapply() be better than lapply()? Also, any suggestions for what to look for when figuring out how to write the code to format the output?

Comment: See `?sapply`, in particular `USE.NAMES=FALSE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the results in an object. Then exclude empty strings (where do they actually come from?) convert `toString` and `cat` it.

```
res <- lapply(mediators, med_overall)
cat(toString(res[res != '']))
# att_admire, att_hypocrisy, att_annoyed, att_respectvalues
```